# U-substitution of 2x in trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, radicals, fractions

Find

$$\int^{3\sqrt{3}/2}_0\frac{x^3}{(4x^2+9)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

The text says to use substitution of $u = 2x$.  How did they get $u = 2x$ and not $u = x^3$?

Comment: [Fractions in indices are hard to read.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189) I've [edit]ed your post to improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $u = 2x$, $du = 2dx$,
$$\int^{3\sqrt3/2}_0\frac{x^3}{(4x^2+9)^{3/2}}dx
= \int^{3\sqrt{3}}_0\frac{u^3/8}{(u^2+9)^{3/2}}\frac{du}{2},
$$
this allows us to do further substitution $u = 3 \tan t$ to get rid of the root sign in the denominator.
If you use $u = x^3$, $du = 3x^2 dx$,
$$\int^{3\sqrt3/2}_0\frac{x^3}{(4x^2+9)^{3/2}}dx
= \int^{81\sqrt{3}/8}_0\frac{\sqrt[3]{u}/3}{(u^{2/3}+9)^{3/2}}du,
$$
which is more complicated then the first equality as this involves the cubic root.

Comment: In the first equation, did you intend to do 3 sqrt(3) instead of dividing it by 2?

Comment: @Jinzu When $x = 3\sqrt3/2$, $u =2x = 3\sqrt{3}$.  Do I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The hint:
$$\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{(4x^2+9)^3}}=\frac{x^3+\frac{9}{4}x-\frac{9}{4}x}{\sqrt{(4x^2+9)^3}}=\frac{x}{4\sqrt{4x^2+9}}-\frac{9x}{4\sqrt{(4x^2+9)^3}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Where did the positive `9/4 x` go? Also why did `x^3` become only `x`?

Comment: Because $x^3+\frac{9}{4}x=\frac{x}{4}(4x^2+9)$ and in the first fraction I divided the nominator and the denominator by $4x^2+9.$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, change:
$$4x^2+9=u \Rightarrow x^2=\frac{u-9}{4}; xdx=\frac{du}{8};$$
$$\int_{9}^{36} \frac{\frac{u-9}{4}\cdot \frac{du}{8}}{u^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{32}\int_{9}^{36} \frac{1}{u^{1/2}}du-\frac{9}{32}\int_{9}^{36} \frac{1}{u^{3/2}}du=\cdots$$